# Error: makes pointer from integer without a cast, al usar strcmp

Tags: array, c, punteros, cast

estoy aprendiendo a programar en **C** y no me queda claro porque tengo este error. Estoy buscando recuperar una lista de A's y F's separadas por comas. Para separar los datos por comas ocupo una función que nombre `lectura()`. El arreglo que obtengo de las letras lo paso por punteros a una región de memoria que establecí con `malloc`. Fuera de la función puedo llamar cada uno de los elementos del array e imprimirlo, pero al usar `strcmp` para comparar elementos del array con caracteres específicos obtengo el siguiente error: `passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`. Espero me puedan ayudar, mi código es el siguiente:

```
int main(){
 
char *arreglo=lectura();
int longitud=sizeof(arreglo)/sizeof(char);
//strncpy(arreglo,arrg, longitud); probé usar strncpy, pero el resultado fue igual

int a=0, f=0,d=0;  
 
  for(int i=0;i<longitud;i++) 
  { 
    if (strcmp(arreglo[i] ,"a") ==0 || strcmp(arreglo[i] ,"A") ==0)
    {
      a=a+1;
    }
   
    else if (strcmp(arreglo[i] ,"f")  ==0 || strcmp(arreglo[i] ,"F") == 0)
    {
      f=f+1;  
    }
    else 
    {
      d=1;  
    }

  }
```

La función lectura() es:

```
char *lectura(){
    
  int longi=0;
  char buffer[1024], * arreglo = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));;     
  char *aux;               
  printf("Introduzca aprobado(A) o reprobado(F) separadas por coma \",\": \n");
  fgets(buffer,1023,stdin); 
  aux=strtok(buffer, ",");  

  while(aux)                 
  { 
  arreglo[longi]= *aux; 
  longi++;                
  aux=strtok(NULL, ",");    
  } 

  return arreglo;
```

Aunque el código puede compilar, al llegar al ciclo `for` de la función original, el programa termina en violación de segmento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strcmp(arreglo[i] ,"a")
```

*arreglo* es un *char**, un puntero a carácter. Pero *arreglo[i]* es el caracter en la posición *i*, no es un puntuero.

*strcmp* compara dos strings que se le pasan como *char** (desde esa posición hasta que encuentra un caracter con el valor ASCII 0). Pero tú le pasas *arreglo[i]* que no es un puntero.

Si lo que quieres es trabajar con caracteres no uses funciones de strings (eso es lo que significa el *str* al principio del nombre). Haz la comparación directamente

```
arreglo[i] == 'a'
```